# Overlay image using css over background image which has fixed aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, background, overlay, aspect-ratio

I have this CSS code which resizes background image according to the browser size keeping the centre of the image always at the centre of browser window! Now the issue is that I need to add another image right at the centre like a icon in the circle which also follows the same rule of maintaining the aspect ratio!

How do I apply the same code to maintain aspect ratio to my second image? And primarily, how do I add another image overlaying the background right at the centre? I have also attached the image of the background achieved using Photoshop!

[image]

**CSS**

```
    #stage {
      position:fixed;
      top:-50%;
      left:-50%;
      width:200%;
      height:200%;
    }

    #stage img {
      position:absolute;
      margin:auto;
      min-width:50%;
      min-height:50%;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 512px) {
      #stage img {
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id=stage>
    <img src="cutest_child_in_the_world-wallpaper-5120x3200.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried just using background-size and background-position to cover the entire viewport and position the background in the center?

Comment: If it is a "background image" then go and use CSS background(-image) property. If it belongs to the real content of the page, then use `img` in HTML. So for background images CSS offers a lot options about resizing, positioning etc.!

Comment: @RDrazard The background image and resizing is working perfectly fine.. What im not able to do is apply the same set of rules to another image that will be centered about the size of the circle and overlay that circle in the screenshot attached here (http://i.imgur.com/52OSjA0.png).. what should i add to my COde? Im sorry im kind of a newbie.. working on college project.. stuck since 2 days

Comment: Well, you have what I assume is the wallpaper in question in the img tag and not as an actual background in your CSS. You could place the icon in the img tag in the stage div to get it in the center. Placing the background as an img would have any additional img stand next to it, unless you use z-index and positioning to force an overlaying effect.

Comment: Thank you All... Just had change the stage into class! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is overlay another image positioned exactly like the first one, then you could just re-use your existing code. Add another div with another image and change the `#stage` ID to a class.

The second image would of course need some transparency in order to see anything of the first... and probably be the exact same size to achieve the desired effect.

Here a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ujzT/1/).

Comment: Thank You Soo Much.. Just The Issue Is The second image that i want to overlay is taking up the whole screen.. i want it to be about 20% of the whole page.. but should always stay in the centre and  same aspect ratio! What should i do in this case?

Comment: You can probably just make the picture larger... add a whole bunch of empty/transparent space around it. I'd make it the same exact size as the image behind it to ensure they both behave the same way.